# Random CPU and case fan speed up to maximum

Tags: fan, cooling

- **Motherboard**: ASRock EP2C602-4L/D16
- **RAM**: Kingston KVR16R11D4K4/64
- **CPUs**: Intel Xeon E5-2670 x2
- **CPU coolers**: Noctua NH-U12DXi4 x2
- **Case fans**: Noctua NF-F12 x6

I have had the system for about a month. I am running Proxmox on it and it is on 24/7. The CPU fans are set to adjust automatically in the BIOS based on temperature, I think it is called 'smart control'. The case fans are set to a specific level in the BIOS so they should always be the same speed.

Randomly all of the fans, CPU and case, start spinning at full speed. The only way to slow them down is to restart the system. It has happened 5-10 times in the month I have had the system. I have software monitoring the system every 60 seconds. Sometimes it records a 'CPU_BSP1 Temp' of ~95C around the time the fans speed up. This is only recorded a single time, so the minute before and after it is at the normal temperature of ~38C. This high temperature isn't always recorded when the fans speed up and sometimes the high temperature is recorded but the fans don't speed up so it may or may not be related.

I am thinking the CPU_BSP1 temperature sensor is bad but it is weird that it fails only briefly. Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Flash the BIOS please first if not done already

Comment: I flashed the BIOS when I received the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same chips and board as you, and I am fairly sure this is a flaw in the motherboard.

My symptoms are exactly the same (false temperature alerts from the BMC for cpus that then cause the fans to spin up to max and stay there). I have tried the automatic smart fan setting in the bios as well as setting to a specific level (1-10). Doesn't seem to make a difference. It behaves as expected until the first false temp alerts (usually several times a week, sometimes several times a day).

There are a few others that have posted about the same issue (See [newegg comments](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157350) on this motherboard, for examples), and I have yet to see a solution other than RMA to ASRock Rack.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, automatic fan control often is quite bugged on many motherboard. If flashing to latest BIOS version does not help, try manually setting a reasonable fan speed at the BIOS level.

Comment: What is weird is that I only have the CPU fans to be automatic, the case fans are manually set. But the case fans also ramp up to full speed.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you might want to put some kind of monitoring in place, to see if there actually a CPU spike during these events.

You mention having monitoring in place to detect the temperature spike, but don't mention whether there is system activity correlating to the event.

It may be there is something (or some combination of things) causing a legitimate spike in CPU usage. That may or may not be compounded by motherboard issues, or indeed by something in your cooling setup.